# do i need to direct to a particular paypal website payment pro url?

Tags: paypal

I am currently using payments standard and moving to payments pro. Both are on paypal hosted pages.

Whenever I am testing however, I seem to be directed to the payments standard page rather than the payments pro page. Is there a particular change in the URL i am meant to use? I cant see anything in the documentation that say this is the case.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're trying to process payments.

Payments Standard and the Hosted Checkout are two different payment methods but can look kind of similar. With Payments Pro you can use Direct Payment API calls to process credit cards directly from your website or redirect your buyers to a secure PayPal site to complete payments.

The URL you use for the secure checkout page through Payments Pro is different. You should be redirecting buyers to https://payflowlink.paypal.com for the live site and https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com for test transactions.